# Unable to successfully extract timestamp to date and time in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp

I am having trouble extracting the time and date from a timestamp. The data is read as a string, so I saw that people are able to use `date_format` to essentially convert it into the format we want. Here is what I tried below

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

data = df_data.select(date_format(F.col("timestamp"),"MM/d/yy").alias("date"),
        date_format(F.col("timestamp"),"HH:mm").alias("time"),
        date_format(F.col("timestamp"), "M/d/yy").alias("current_date_formated")).show(10)
```

My input data looks like this:

```
  timestamp
11/9/18 14:11
11/9/18 14:27
11/9/18 14:42
11/9/18 14:57
```

The output of my code above is spewed as under my `date` and `time` alias returns rows of `null`. I have also tried using `to_date` but didn't work either

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = df_data.select(date_format(F.col("timestamp"),"MM/d/yy").alias("date"),
        F.to_date(F.col("timestamp"),"HH:mm").alias("time"),
        F.to_date(F.col("timestamp"), "M/d/yy").alias("current_date_formated")).show(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea with `date_format`. The only thing your missing is it to **first and foremost** convert your **string timestamp** to **Timestamp Type**. And then you can do your formatting. I assumed your `input data` is in the format of **day-month-year**, if not, you can switch it to `"MM/dd/yy HH:mm"`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("timestamp", F.to_timestamp("timestamp","dd/MM/yy HH:mm"))\
  .withColumn("time",F.date_format("timestamp","HH:mm"))\
  .withColumn("current_date_formated",F.date_format("timestamp", "M/d/yy")).show()

+-------------------+-----+---------------------+
|          timestamp| time|current_date_formated|
+-------------------+-----+---------------------+
|2018-09-11 14:11:00|14:11|              9/11/18|
|2018-09-11 14:27:00|14:27|              9/11/18|
|2018-09-11 14:42:00|14:42|              9/11/18|
|2018-09-11 14:57:00|14:57|              9/11/18|
+-------------------+-----+---------------------+
```

Comment: Everything seems to return null. Also, when I print the types of each column it returns as a string, which is confusing because we're converting the columns when using date_format.

Comment: You are not converting anything by using date_format, as it only operates on `datetype` or `timestamptype`. use my **code above**.

Comment: **before** you can apply `date_format`, you need to **convert** your **string** timestamp **to timestamp type**

Comment: I just got it to work! I needed to have the date format to be `"M/d/yy"` every time I would format the date